# How to properly build include a small library/namespace in a ROS-Project

Tags: ros-kinetic, roscpp, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS project consisting of several nodes each of which is built from the CMakeLists like this:

```
add_executable(node1 src/node1.cpp src/node1callback.cpp)  
target_link_libraries(node1 ${catkin_LIBRARIES})  
add_dependencies(node 1 my_ros_project_generate_messages_cpp)
```

Now I would like to write a small library (not sure if this is the right word) consisting of a .h and a .cpp file defining a namespace with a couple of functions that I use in multiple nodes.
Now my question is: How do I add this library to the CMakeLists? Do I add it in the same way even though it's not a node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313348/how-to-properly-build-include-a-small-library/namespace-in-a-ros-project/) by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2019-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-22**:
An observation: please realise this is not ROS-specific, but a general CMake workflow question. `add_library(..)` as suggested by @Sebastian Kasperski is a regular CMake function, and the rest of the additions/changes to your `CMakeLists.txt` would be as well.

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2019-01-22**:
@gvdhoorn You are right, sorry. I'll consider other forums the next time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-22**:
@max11gen: I did not make my comment to tell you to go to other fora. I merely wanted to make sure you did not assume this was something ROS-specific.

Many times I've had to explain that Catkin is essentially "some" convenience macros for CMake. Just wanted to make sure you understood that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you just use add_library instead of add_executable. Make sure to add your library to the target_link_libraries afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2019-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2